# How is the sample variance an unbiased estimator for population variance?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I know some variation of this question has been asked repeatedly, but I don't think any of them answer my particular question.

I understand the definition of a maximum likelihood estimator and the proof that $\displaystyle \hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{2}$ is the MLE of $\sigma^{2}$.  I also understand that $E(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{(n-1)}{n}\sigma^{2}$ and that therefore $\displaystyle S^{2} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{2}$ is unbiased.

What I don't understand is how we know that $S^{2}$ is still an estimator for $\sigma^{2}$.  The calculation for the MLE resulted in $\hat{\theta}$, so wouldn't this still be the best guess for $\sigma^{2}$, even if that guess is biased?  In what sense is $S^{2}$ better, if it doesn't maximize the likelihood of the population parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First ask yourself, what does it mean for a statistic to be an estimator?  Do all estimators have to be "good" ones?

Next, the MLE is "best" in the sense that such a choice maximizes the likelihood function for the observed sample, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is the only suitable choice for an estimator.  It is in some sense the most likely choice for the parameter given the data we observed, but from the point of view of biasedness, it tends to underestimate the true variance.  That is to say, the MLE for $\sigma^2$ will, on average, give an estimate that is too small for a fixed sample size, whereas $s^2$ does not have this problem, especially when the sample size is small.

We can also think of the quality of an estimator as being judged by other desirable properties; e.g., consistency, asymptotic unbiasedness, minimum mean squared error, or UMVUE.  Maximum likelihood is just one possible criterion.

Comment: Hm, this is certainly the sort of answer I was looking for, but I'm still having a hard time coming to terms with it! :) I guess I just can't resist the intuitive urge to say, by choosing anything other than the MLE, I'm not maximizing my likelihood.

Comment: I would perhaps be more at ease if I had a guarantee that, given $E(\hat{\theta})=\theta$ , this ensures $\hat{\theta}$ was a good estimator of $\theta$.  But it seems to me that this just says, if you sample and compute $\hat{\theta}$ you'll typically get $\theta$.  But that seems weaker than what the MLE gives, which is guaranteed to the be most likely of all the estimators.

Comment: Well, you're not maximizing the likelihood if you don't choose an MLE.  But why is it necessary to maximize the likelihood?  Consider also that the MLE is not necessarily unique:  there are situations where the likelihood function is maximized at more than one value of the parameter, or even at an infinite number of values.  The MLE corresponds to a *mode* of the likelihood.  Just as there are other measures of central tendency for a probability distribution besides the mode, there are other ways to characterize the goodness of an estimator.

Comment: To elaborate, the likelihood is proportional to a posterior distribution on the parameter for a given observed sample.  The true value of the parameter remains unknown to us.  The MLE is merely a **point estimate.**  We could provide interval estimates for the parameter, or a Bayesian would specify the posterior distribution as their belief/"estimate" of the parameter.  As for biasedness, there are in general an infinite number of unbiased estimators for a given parameter, so unbiasedness (${\rm E}[\hat\theta] = \theta$) alone is not a sufficient criterion by which to judge an estimator.

Answer (score 0):

Bias of the estimator is the difference between the expected value of the estimator and the true value: $$\operatorname{Bias_\Omega}[\hat\Omega]=\operatorname{E_{\Omega}}[\hat \Omega]-\Omega$$

When this difference is zero the estimator is said to be unbiased.

Now when we are estimating $\sigma^2$ with $\hat\theta$ and $S^2$:

If $\operatorname{E_\theta}[\hat\theta] = \frac{n-1}n \sigma^2$ then the bias is $$\operatorname{Bias_\theta}[\hat\theta]=\frac{n-1}n\sigma^2 - \sigma^2 \\ = \frac{-\sigma^2}n $$

If $S^2 = \frac n{n-1} \hat\theta$ then $\operatorname{E_\theta}[S^2] = \frac n{n-1}E[\hat\theta]$ and the bias is: $$\operatorname{Bias_\theta}[S^2]=\frac n{n-1}\frac {n-1}n\sigma^2-\sigma^2 \\ = 0$$

Comment: Right, I understand all that.  What I don't understand is how you can jump from the fact that E(S^2) = sigma^2 to the idea that S^2 is the best estimate for sigma^2.  I mean, it's not the statistic that maximizes likelihood for the observed data.

Comment: Maybe to put it another way:  I am sold on the idea that the MLE is a good way to make a guess about an unknown population parameter based on a sample.  Why should I change my choice of estimate, based on the expected value of the distribution of the MLE?  Won't anything other than the MLE, by definition, not be the most likely parameter?

Comment: @Addem The MLE is biased by being derived from a random sample of a normally distributed population.  To get a better estimator you need to account for (and remove) that bias.